# android set listview height dynamically

Tags: android, listview, height, parameters

i have `ExpandableListview` inside `ScrollView` and i know that's not good but i had too, the only solution to show the whole list is by set its height by code using `layoutParams`

> RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new
>   RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
>   ListViewData.length());

this solution is good but i can't figure the right height that i should give in the `Params`, SO is there a way to know the actual size from the size of the array

**Edit:**
i came up with a solution that everytime i expand a group of the list am gonna change the height to fit with new geight

Comment: hey, will you write your solution?

Answer (score 16):

try this, Use Child based on listview. `setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren()` this will set your listview child based height

```
 public class Utils {

public static void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {
    ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter(); 
    if (listAdapter == null) {
        // pre-condition
        return;
    }

    int totalHeight = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        View listItem = listAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);
        listItem.measure(0, 0);
        totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
    }

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
    listView.setLayoutParams(params);
    listView.requestLayout();
}



}
```

Comment: mmmmmmmm okay i'll try it now

Comment: It's working but you should be add a origin of these solution.

Comment: @Murali Ganesan i want to use above code for gridview, what code to replace to get the DividerHeight() of Grideview.Thanx

Comment: `listView.requestLayout()` is already called when `listView.setLayoutParams(params)` is called and should be removed.

Comment: I must say its a clean logic and most of the time it worked. But rarely the height it is setting is much more than the height it should set. Don't know why but this code has some flaw in few cases.

Answer (score 10):

**Your ListView is effectively unneeded in this case**. You can as well loop over your adapter's items and just add them to a vertical LinearLayout inside your ScrollView.

In case you do not want to change a lot of code:

Replace `ListView.setAdapter` with

```
LinearLayout ll; //this should be the vertical LinearLayout that you substituted the listview with
for(int i=0;i<adapter.getCount();i++) {
    View v = adapter.getView(position, null, null);
    ll.addView(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
}
```

If you already use an OnItemClickListener add after `View v = adapter.getView(position, null, null);` the following

```
final int position = i;
v.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public onClick(View v) {
        yourOnItemClickListener.onItemClick(null, v, position, 0);
    }
});
```

---

In this case you do not have to worry about any miscalculation in the height.

Comment: i came up with this solution in case of listView, but now it's gonna change to ExpandableListView :/ , so in this case too its gonna have to done dynamically

Comment: I think you should create a new question for that edit. You specifically asked for a listview.

Comment: and Hi from Lebanon (:

Comment: This is ultimately the better solution.  Hacking a `ListView` wasn't working in every scenario with various elements that the rows could contain, like dynamic multi-line `TextView`s or sub `ListView`s

Answer (score 4):

Try this, it works for my same problem

```
public static boolean setListViewHeightBasedOnItems(ListView listView) {

ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
if (listAdapter != null) {

    int numberOfItems = listAdapter.getCount();

    // Get total height of all items.
    int totalItemsHeight = 0;
    for (int itemPos = 0; itemPos < numberOfItems; itemPos++) {
        View item = listAdapter.getView(itemPos, null, listView);
        item.measure(0, 0);
        totalItemsHeight += item.getMeasuredHeight();
    }

    // Get total height of all item dividers.
    int totalDividersHeight = listView.getDividerHeight() * 
            (numberOfItems - 1);

    // Set list height.
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = totalItemsHeight + totalDividersHeight;
    listView.setLayoutParams(params);
    listView.requestLayout();

    return true;

} else {
    return false;
}}
```

**requestLayout()** method is called on the view because something has changed that invalidated its layout - forces redrawing.

Comment: **NPE** is thrown at `item.measure(0, 0);`.

Answer (score 0):

you can set a variable in dimensions file for different screen sizes and then multiply it by the number of items of list you want to display.

Comment: i tried to use a fixed variable then multiply it by the number of items, but its not working in different screen sizes

Comment: @alaa7731 that's what i said, you need to set different values for different screen sizes.